# Fetch returns undefined when imported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

I have a function that fetches data from the url and is supposed to return it:

```
const fetchTableData = () => {
fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/15psn9')
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(data => {
        return data;
    })
}

export default fetchTableData;
```

The problem is that when i import this function and try to use it, it always returns `undefined`.

When i console log the data inside the function itself, you can see it is available. The function just doesn't work when i try to import it.

What is the problem here? Why does it work that way?

Comment: You should add the code where you implemented it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this =) You have to return something from the fetchTableData function also.

```
const fetchTableData = () => {
  const fetchedData = fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/15psn9')
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(data => {
        return data;
    })

    return fetchedData;
}

export default fetchTableData;
```

Or you can just return it like this:

```
const fetchTableData = () => {
      return fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/15psn9')
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(data => {
            return data;
        })
    }

    export default fetchTableData;
```

Comment: Wonderful, works like a charm. Thanks! 

May you please add a reminder that this way `fetchTableData()` returns a Promise and its data needs to accessed using another `then`?

It would save couple of minutes for other newbies like me, that come around this question.

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    const data = fetch("http://localhost:4000/profile/address")
      .then((res) => {
        res = res.json();
      })
      .then((res) => {
        return res;
      });
    console.log(data);
  }

The console displays: 
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined


please Help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You need to either store data in a global variable or assign any variable to fetch to get return data.

```js
//First way
fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/15psn9')
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log("data",data);
    });
    
//Second way
let binData = null;

fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/15psn9')
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(data => {
        binData = data;
        console.log("binData", binData);
    });
```

Here is the working example.

Answer (score 3):

In your code you were not returning from the `fetchTableData` function. Only from the the second `then()` callback. When a function has no return value, `undefined` will be returned.

Try this instead:

```
const fetchTableData = () => {
const myResponse = fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/15psn9')
    .then(result => result.json())
    .then(data => {
        return data;
    })
return myResponse;
}

export default fetchTableData;
```

What now happens is the following:

1. The response return by the second `then()` function is returning the data.
2. We are saving this data in a variable, named `myResponse`.
3. We are now returning this value from the function `fetchTableData`.